# c# - interop word 2010 databound combobox issue

Tags: c#, office-interop

I have a VS2012 Word document project that loads up a Windows Form when the document loads, and it contains a ComboBox that is bound to data on an SQL server.  When debugging, it all works flawlessly.  The ComboBox gets its data.

When I publish the document, run the setup it creates to install the necessary files, and then open the document, I verified the form is receiving the proper data from the SQL server in both the DataView and the DataTable, but it refuses to populate the combobox.

On form load (also tried in a button):

```
DataView dv = document.tickets.DefaultView;
DataTable distinctClients = dv.ToTable(true, "Client");
comboBox1.DataSource = distinctClients;
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Client";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "Client";
```

Comment: Same results when putting the ComboBox on the document directly - the ComboBox gets its items correctly when debugging, but not when just loading the document after publishing.